# Expected File format for altool upload-app for Mac OS App Store app?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, mac-app-store

I'm packaging my application for the Mac App Store, using the following command

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --file MyApp.??? --type osx <credentials>
```

I see on some examples they are using `MyApp.zip` as the file, and some it is `MyApp.pkg`.

`altool` does not seem happy with simply `MyApp.app` as a zip file, keeps throwing a lot of errors about the Info.plist which are not accurate.

The most success I've had so far is using `productbuild` to create a `pkg`, but now it is demanding that I sign it with my "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" certificate.

Is it required that you create a signed PKG to deploy to the Mac App Store with `altool`, or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seems to be, Yes, a PKG is required.

It's not well documented, but it would appear that the Mac App Store uses the PKG to install your application upon delivery.

You must create the following:

- PKG for delivery
- signing certificate for the Mac App
- signing certificate for the Mac Installer.

Here's an example of a script that's working for me.

```
codesign -vfs "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyGreatCompany (XXXXXXXX)" MyApp.app

xcrun productbuild --component MyApp.app /Applications/ myapp.unsigned.pkg

xcrun productsign --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: MyGreatCompany (XXXXXXXX)" myapp.unsigned.pkg myapp.pkg

xcrun altool --upload-app --file myapp.pkg --type osx
```